# Equivalent of ZStack in UIKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I roughed together a UI in SwiftUI to get approval from our design team. I'm implementing the project in UIKit, though, and there seems to be no such element as a ZStack.

I need this, because I have a complex element that stacks an image that gets changed according to app conditions, under a button that the user interacts with. The two elements share a horizontal and vertical alignment, with the button on top.

I arrange a series of these in an HStacks, that then are arranged in a VStack to make a 3 x 3 matrix of elements. Attached is a pdf of the UI design.

How can I use an HStack/VStack combination with UI elements occupying the same space, so they don't become sequential elements in the HStacks, as I can do in SwiftUI?[image: UI Mockup]

Comment: to be clear, the UI elements that exemplify this are the 5 spelling BADGE in the top row. But the UI grids at the bottom half are made up of the same components.

Comment: Why do you need UIKit? You can expose SwiftUI views to UIKit, so I really don't see a reason why you'd want to rewrite a perfectly working SwiftUI view in UIKit (unless of course you need to support iOS 12 and lower.

Comment: [ZStack - View/s] (in SwiftUI) is equivalent to [UIView - subview/s] (in UIKit)